# Upload zip file to AWS Lambda using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Is there an AWS Java method to upload the zip file to AWS Lambda? All examples either use CLI `aws` or upload via the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [createFunction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#createFunction-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.CreateFunctionRequest-) or  [updateFunctionCode](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#updateFunctionCode-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.UpdateFunctionCodeRequest-) methods of the [AWSLambdaClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html) class to upload the zip file to Lambda using the AWS SDK for Java.

Comment: The zip file itself gets set for the FunctionCode for [CreateFunctionRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/CreateFunctionRequest.html#setCode-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.FunctionCode-) passed to the createFunction and on the UpdateFunctionCodeRequest for [updateFunctionCode](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/CreateFunctionRequest.html#setCode-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.FunctionCode-) passed to updateFunctionCode

Answer (score 1):

Read the following docs:

[Learn how to use AWS Lambda to easily create infinitely scalable web services](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-aws-lambda#hello-world-example-api-gateway)

[Class AWSLambdaClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#updateFunctionCode-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.UpdateFunctionCodeRequest-)

Answer (score 0):

Using following link you can find out how to upload your Java based function to Lambda using Maven and CLI functionalities.

> Following steps will help to You

- Create a project directory
- create build.gradle
- Handle folder structure
- build and package the project in a .zip file

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question is about uploading the zip file but it can help someone else. If you are using `Eclipse` then you can use the `aws plugin` to package code and then upload as lambda function to `AWS Account`.

[Eclipse Plugin to Upload Java Lambda Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html)

Plugin will ask for the following information:

1. credentials: which plugin can read from credentials file in `.aws`
   directory.
2. role: name of role which will be assumed by lambda when executed.
3. bucketName: where zip file will be stored.
4. Other Settings such as Region, Memory etc